# Express all variables in terms of one in a recurrence relation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

Good day to all!

I have a recursive relation given by
$$
a_{k, k + 1} f_{k + 1} = \sum_{k_1 = 0}^{k - 1} a_{k, k - k_1} f_{k - k_1},
$$
the first equation of which provides
$$
f_2 = \frac{a_{1, 1}}{a_{1, 2}} f_1.
$$
Substituting it into the third equation, provides
$$
f_3 = \frac{1}{a_{2, 3}} \left( \frac{a_{1, 1} a_{2, 2}}{a_{1, 2}} + a_{2, 1} \right) f_1.
$$
Substituting the expressions for $f_2$ and $f_3$ into $f_4$, we will be able to represent it in terms of $f_1$.

Apparently, with increase of $k$, the expressions get more complicated. Is there a way to express $f_k$ in terms of $f_1$ for arbitrary $k$?